# Creating siamese network with tensorflow estimator and hub

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

I attempting to finetune the universal sentence encoder by creating a siamese network with the encoder.  I would like to train the weights of the tensorflow_hub universal encoder module during training but I am not certain how to do this using estimator.

My questions is if with my setup below using two hub.text_embedding_column will it train two separate networks rather than training them like they are a siamese network.  If the wieghts are not shared how would I change it so that the weights are shared and trained.  I can load the modules from a local machine if that helps.

```
def train_and_evaluate_with_module(hub_module, train_module=False):
    embedded_text_feature_column1 = hub.text_embedding_column(
      key="sentence1", module_spec=hub_module, trainable=train_module)

    embedded_text_feature_column2 = hub.text_embedding_column(
      key="sentence2", module_spec=hub_module, trainable=train_module)


    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
      hidden_units=[500, 100],
      feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column1,embedded_text_feature_column2],
      n_classes=2,
      optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))

    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)

    train_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_train_input_fn)
    test_eval_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=predict_test_input_fn)

    training_set_accuracy = train_eval_result["accuracy"]
    test_set_accuracy = test_eval_result["accuracy"]

    return {
      "Training accuracy": training_set_accuracy,
      "Test accuracy": test_set_accuracy
    }



results  = train_and_evaluate_with_module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with how to use `tf.estimator` but when it comes to having a siamese architecture, this is sufficient:

```
sentences1 = ["the cat sat on the mat", "the cat didn't sat on the mat"]
sentences2 = ["the dog sat on the mat", "the dog didn't sat on the mat"]
encoder = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3", trainable=True)
sentences1_embedding = encoder(sentences1)
sentences2_embedding = encoder(sentences2)
# Now, you can proceed with doing whatever you want with the embeddings
```

Then, when you compute the loss and backpropagate the gradients, the `universal-sentence-encoder` will be updated from both branches of your model.

In other words, create one instance of the module, and use it to obtain embeddings from two or more sentences → Siamese neural network.

---

In your case, I assume that the following should be sufficient:

```
embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
  key="sentence", module_spec=hub_module, trainable=train_module)

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
  hidden_units=[500, 100],
  feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column, embedded_text_feature_column],
  n_classes=2,
  optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.003))
```

So, you instanciate one `text_embedding_column` with a `module`, and then you use the same `text_embedding_column` to embed both feature columns in your `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm trying to find the answer with regards to estimator framework as I am much less fluent at Tensorflow than pytorch and am looking just to quickly test something

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The key with embedded_text_feature_column corresponds to the input from the data.  So both the embedded_text_feature_column feature would be the same value.  I am trying to pass different sentences  to the model.  The idea is to embed two sentences with on single embedding model and then put a classifier on the end to predict how related the sentences are based on a label.  I am using this to fine tune USE.  If you have a better or simpler idea for how to fine tune USE I would love to hear.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do what you want in current setup.

Comment: Yeah thats the conclusion that I was coming to.  Do you know if I attach the estimator to the end of the regular hub.module() then run optimizer will it train the model.  Most of the tutorials I have run into wrap the hub in a keras layer so that it can't be trained.